# I have to log in twice in joomla backend

Tags: joomla

Do you know why a customer has to login twice in Joomla backend and MS Edge ? it works for him with Firefox  but he wants to use Edge

thanks

Comment: Did you try yourself? Is the problem reproduced? Does he have to login twice only on joomla or on the other sites as well?

Comment: Solved with  $live_site = ''